# Question about converting PayPal funds (and quickly)

Tags: paypal, virtual-credit-card

I have a pretty specific (and probably strange) question.

I am in a situation where I'm currently without a bank account (due to having just had one closed), but I am responsible for paying a particular bill by the 10th of this month. It's a phone/internet bill. The company I am paying accepts funds by electronic check or credit/debit.

I have a PayPal account with $500 in it. I cannot get a PayPal debit card sent to me before this deadline. Do you know of any quick solutions? What is the likelihood that I can purchase some pre-paid card, digitally, and have it accepted? Is there anything that comes to mind on how I could have funds from a PayPal account converted to something more spendable within a few hours?

Answer (score 1):

In the US [you can walk into some retail stores](http://www.cnet.com/news/paypals-in-store-payment-partners-grow-to-23-retailers/) and use your paypal to pay directly. Some of them sell prepaid debit card. By one and use it to pay your bill.

If you're not in the US - check if some local retailers allow that. I believe in the UK they have some that allow paypal as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about finding a friend with Paypal and sending them the money so they can pay your bill using a card? Withdrawals from Paypal are typically instant now.

Comment: Paypal's Instant Transfers are "instant" for PayPal-account-to-PayPal-account, and only apply to transfers that use PayPal balance or bank account transfers. This does not apply to withdrawals of the PayPal balance to bank accounts. There's still a 2-3 day delay, depending on the bank.

Comment: Guess that is UK only then - here you can transfer any amount from Paypal to a linked bank account instantly, and have been able to for quite a while (12 months+ ?)